# undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass during a db:auto:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, date, null, migrate

I'm trying to run a db:auto:migrate in my system and it keep throwing the undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass whenever it gets to a column that uses a type of date.  If I change the field to a datetime and run the migrate, it will change the field to a date with no errors.  What is causing this problem.  I have to keep changing the field type every time I want to run my migration.

The reason I'm using the date type instead of the datetime is because I am trying to output the date and Rails keeps adjusting the data for my time zone, which is giving out bad data.

Thank you.

Josh

Comment: what part of the migration is causing this? can you please post some code?

Comment: What's the output of `rake db:migrate --trace`? This will show you what module is generating the malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you named a column wrong and somehow the sql table got generated. I trying to get this fixed right now. This has happened before and I just rebuild the table.

For example, you might have spelled integer as integre and that messes up everything. That is what I did anyways.

Comment: how did you fix that, if you try to alter or drop that column in a migration then you get the same error